# How to fix "Error spawn Unknown system error -8" in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have that weird error when running "npx react-native run-android" that is only occuring in a specific react native project only on my Macbook with android simulator. Other RN apps are running fine on my mac with android.
On a windows pc this specific RN app is also working fine.

```
Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:743:9)
at module.exports (/Users/hannes/Projects/test2/mapp/native-frame/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:205:26)
```

I tried the following things:

- deleting package-lock.json
- rm -r node_modules + gradlew clean (in android folder)
- creating a new virtual device in android studio with API level according to build.gradle
- upgrading node to 18.8.0
- upgrading npm to 8.18.0
- npm cache clean –force

Somebody any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After using "run-ios" in the meantime I had to face the problem again and found a solution.

`npx react-native run-android`
this line is using the port 8081 and my macbook did sometimes use this port for another service

`lsof -i tcp:8081`
this command showed the process that was running

```
COMMAND   PID   FD   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node      44492 24u  0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
```

I terminated this process but still got the error message.
So I called the gradle command for building and installing the app myself.

`cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`

This worked, the app got build and installed on my android device but I got multiple error messages in the android studio run console starting with:

`Could not find generated setter for class`
this error was also addressed on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6692) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981703/react-native-could-not-find-generated-setter-for-class)

So building and installing the app in production mode solved the problem for me.

`./gradlew app:installRelease`